# ASP.NET MVC validate model dataanotations using mvvm in controler

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, mvvm, controller

If I have data annotations in the Model and use ViewModels in my views, how I can validate my Model data annotations in the controller?

EDIT:
Thanks for the answers, i found just the solution

Comment: Could you please provide a code sample demonstrating what you have tried so far?

Comment: `ModelState.IsValid` should work for you, if you have included the data annotation in the models that you are including in VM

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
---viewmodel controler action---
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
   var model = new Model();
   UpdateModel(model, viewModel);

   var result = new List<ValidationResult>();
   var context = new ValidationContext(model, serviceProvider: null, items: null);
   var isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(model, context, result, true);
   if (!isValid)
   {
      foreach (var validationResult in result)
      {
         ModelState.AddModelError("",validationResult.ErrorMessage);
      }
   }
```